# Input cursor windows phone phonegap

Tags: windows, cordova, windows-phone-8, input

I develop an app for Windows Phone 8.1 with phonegap . The problem is that when I try to write some text in a input text, the virtual keyboard is opened, the inputs move up and the cursor is positioned wrong.

This problem occurs every time the softkeyboard is opened for writing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION: This problem appeared when I put my solution "retarget to Windows Phone 8.1". Compile the application to 8.0 and disappeared mistake again.